# How to kick a user using slash commands Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make my Discord bot kick a member, and send that "user banned because reason" to a specific channel and not the channel the command was used.
The code I'm using:

```
@bot.slash_command(description = "Kick someone", guild_ids=[1041057700823449682])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
@option("member",description = "Select member")
@option("reason",description = "Reason for kick (you can leave this empty)")
async def kick(
    ctx, 
    member: discord.Member,
    channel: bot.get_channel(1042042492020863037),
    *, 
    reason=None):
    if reason==None:
      reason="(no reason)"
    await ctx.guild.kick(member)
    await ctx.respond("Done :)")
    await ctx.channel.send(f'User {member.mention} was kicked because {reason}')
```

When I try using this code I get a few errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\fonti\Documents\Projetos Python\Bot do Discord\Iniciar Bot.py", line 152, in <module>
    async def kick(
  File "C:\Users\fonti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 905, in decorator
    self.add_application_command(result)
  File "C:\Users\fonti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 127, in add_application_command
    command._set_cog(None)
  File "C:\Users\fonti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 603, in _set_cog
    self.cog = cog
  File "C:\Users\fonti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 827, in cog
    self._validate_parameters()
  File "C:\Users\fonti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 705, in _validate_parameters
    self.options: list[Option] = self._parse_options(params)
  File "C:\Users\fonti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 745, in _parse_options
    option = Option(option)
  File "C:\Users\fonti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\options.py", line 210, in __init__
    self.input_type = SlashCommandOptionType.from_datatype(input_type)
  File "C:\Users\fonti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\enums.py", line 707, in from_datatype
    if datatype.__name__ in ["Member", "User"]:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__name__'. Did you mean: '__ne__'?
```

I was trying to send the message...

```
(f'User {member.mention} was kicked because {reason}')
```

to a specific channel. If I remove the channel condition, the bot works, but sends this message to the channel the command was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the cause of your error is your channel definition inside your kick command definition. Try removing the channel definition from your kick command definition and put it inside the function instead. The way I have it setup on my bot, other than the channel definition, is the same as yours and mine works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

To send it in the channel, instead of using `ctx.channel.send`, you can use `ctx.send`. I think that's where you're running into your error. Also here's how I tend to set up my kick command using slash commands so that my answer makes more sense:

```
@nextcord.slash_command() # I use nextcord, a dpy fork so your setup is gonna be different
@commands.has_permissions(whatever permissions you want)
async def kickuser(self, ctx, member : nextcord.Member, *, reason='None'): # default reason is none so that it is optional in the slash command
      # side note for nextcord.Member, having it there makes it so that there's a drop down menu that functions the same way as if you were to @ someone in a message. This makes it easier to kick the right person        
      embed = discord.Embed(description=f'You have been kicked from {ctx.guild} for reason: {reason}')
      
      embed = nextcord.Embed(description=f'{member} has been kicked for reason: {reason}') # setting up embed to send
      await ctx.send(embed=embed) # sends the embed in chat letting people know the person has been kicked
      await member.kick(reason=reason) # actually kicking the person, this comes after all the other steps so that we are able to mention and direct message them that they have been kicked
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But this doesn't really ask my question. This sends a message in the channel I used it, not the channel I want.

Comment: dont use ctx.channel.send then, just use channel.send since you already got the channel you want

Comment: using ctx.something isnt neccessary for every situation, I would suggest reading more of the docs

Comment: Sam Shields, what do you mean by "you already got the channel you want"?

Comment: Sorry i should have clarified, i'm referring to this: ```channel: bot.get_channel(1042042492020863037)``` where you are grabbing the specific channel you want to send the message in

Comment: Removing channel from ctx.channel.send gives me the error I stated in my original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249643/discussion-between-jack142-and-sam-shields).

Comment: No I mean remove the ctx from ctx.channel.send not the channel. Use channel.send

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives me same error.

Comment: Ok, try removing the channel definition from your kick command definition and put it inside the function instead. The way I have it setup on my bot is the same as yours and mine works perfectly. That's the only other thing I could think of changing that would make a significant difference

Comment: Oh my god, finally! Thanks! Can you make your comment as an answer so I can flag this post as answered?

Comment: sounds good ill do that now

Answer (score 0):

This snip of code uses PyCord ( Confirmed to work by myself )

```
@discord.default_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        await ctx.respond(f'{member.mention} has been kicked!')
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question...

Comment: async def kick(
    ctx, 
    member: discord.Member,
    channel: bot.get_channel(1042042492020863037),
    *, 
    reason=None):
    **if reason==None:
      reason="(no reason)"** --- Try adding this. I think this might be the issue
       **else:
          reason==reason**

Now go with the rest of the code.

Comment: What is the difference between this and what I have in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Just get a channel object with `bot.get_channel()`

Then use the channels `send()` function to send your message.
Also, `:` after arguments in function definitions are type hints, they are made for IDEs, if you want to assign a default value, you have to use `=` instead. (Look at your channel argument)

EDIT

You are using [type hints](https://realpython.com/lessons/type-hinting/) in your code. Type hints are made for IDEs in first place, so they can show you mistakes in your code more easier. But you are „setting“ a value in it with the function, but this is for discord.py `None`, thats causing your error. Use `:` for showing which class an argument has to be. But use `=` for setting a [default value](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/), if this argument is not being passed.

```py
def function(type_hint: str, default_value = 0, mixed : int = 10):
    print(type_hint, default_value, mixed)
```

Answer again if you need even further help ;-)

Comment: What do you mean? I'm a beginner at python and didn't understand you.

Comment: Then I really suggest that you watch python tutorials first. That what I wrote is basic python and not even complex words. I try to rephrase it for you now…